# How to run pkexec in a vala script?

Tags: ubuntu, vala

I want to run a GUI with root permissions. When the user runs the script, a popup should open asking root password and later GUI should open. I know it can be done through pkexec. But I don't know how to implement pkexec in vala script. Inshort, I want to run my app through sudo permissions. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run part of code as root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779843/run-part-of-code-as-root)

Answer (score 0):

Just take the example code from [GLib.Process.spawn_async](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Process.spawn_async.html) and modify it to run your `my_elevated_app`.

`main.vala` (The code for the executable that should run as the normal user):

```
public static int main (string[] args) {
    stdout.printf ("I am running as a normal user\n");
    MainLoop loop = new MainLoop ();
    try {
        string[] spawn_args = {"pkexec", "elevated_app", "arg1", "arg2"};
        string[] spawn_env = Environ.get ();
        Pid child_pid;

        Process.spawn_async ("/",
            spawn_args,
            spawn_env,
            SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH | SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
            null,
            out child_pid);

        ChildWatch.add (child_pid, (pid, status) => {
            // Triggered when the child indicated by child_pid exits
            Process.close_pid (pid);
            loop.quit ();
        });

        loop.run ();
    } catch (SpawnError e) {
        stdout.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`elevated_main.vala` (The code for the executable that should run as root):

```
public static int main (string[] args) {
    stdout.printf ("I am running as root\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile the two executables like usual:

```
valac -o my_app main.vala
valac -o my_elevated_app elevated_main.vala
```

Note that with the above code you have to install the elevated executable first (i.e. to `/usr/local/bin/` or `/usr/bin/` or any other directory in your PATH environment), for example:

```
sudo install -m 755 my_elevated_app /usr/local/bin
```

Of course you could change the code to run it in the local working directory, but running something as root is dangerous, you should always make sure that your are running the correct executable. Some developers even go as far as only allowing a specific filename (like `/usr/bin/my_elevated_app`).

When you now run `./my_app` you should get prompted by `pkexec` with a GUI to enter your password and after successful authentication the `my_elevated_app` process should be started.

If everything worked as expected you should see this output:

```
$ ./my_app
I am running as a normal user
I am running as root
```

Both of the above apps are console applications, but the same thing should work for GUI apps as well (just create your windows with Gtk as usual, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for answering.Apparently my elevated_gui_app is the app which I get after running two vala scripts(main.vala and main1.vala).So,how to call these scripts(or app after compiling and running the two scripts) in the above example code?

Comment: I have clarified my answer. Please do not use the term `script` in the context of vala, `.vala` files are called `source files` and the result after compiling is called an `application` (or `app` for short). Well to be 100% technically correct we should call it `executable`.

Comment: The content of the source files are called `source code` (or `code` for short).

Comment: getting error while running `./my_app`. This is the [error](http://pastebin.com/eKtXegHF). I am calling a `gui_app` from main.vala as you said.

Comment: These are errors related to the display server, look at askubuntu.com: https://askubuntu.com/questions/871092/failed-to-connect-to-mir-failed-to-connect-to-server-socket-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: Take a look at the `.policy` file, it shows how to allow to run a GUI app using pkexec: https://greyok.github.io/simple-polkit-tutorial.html