# run part of code as root

Tags: gtk, root, gtk3, vala

I have a package which runs uses Gtk and written in vala.A dialog box or a gui opens after selecting a file.I want this dialog box or gui to run as root so as to open and read the files which don't open with normal users.I have this code

```
static void open_file(string filename) {
    selected_file = filename;
    stdout.printf(selected_file);
    new ProgressWindow(selected_file, {});
```

}

I want to run `ProgressWindow` to run as root.Is it possible?

Comment: Please stop creating duplicate questions about the same topic. I have marked your other three question as possible duplicates of this one now.

Answer (score 4):

No. To run as root, it must be in a separate process and you must run that process using `pkexec` via PolicyKit. Here's a [tutorial on PolicyKit](https://greyok.github.io/simple-polkit-tutorial.html) in Vala.